# When describing changes of the E-field with distance, is it the 'Distribution of', 'Repartition of', 'Variation of' (or, simply) the Electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

--Unsure if this is a question for Physics or for language/English stackexchange, asking this in Physics as I assume more people here are familiar with these notions in scientific talk--

I have a 2D figure (labeled 'Figure 1') that represents the discrete values of the Electric field *E* (on the ordinate) at different points along the *x*-axis (the abscissa) between, say, 0 and 0.6 mm (representing the thickness of a sample).

[image: Figure 1, Electric field vs x]

I want to describe this figure. How should I go about it?

1. Figure 1 presents the distribution of the Electric field with the depth of the sample
2. Figure 1 presents the repartition of the Electric field with the depth of the sample
3. Figure 1 presents the variation of the Electric field with the depth of the sample
4. Figure 1 presents the Electric field with the depth of the sample

So far, I've received feedback that:

- Distribution is more about statistics, and how often a value appears in a set data (like histogram plots)
- Variation is more about the changes of the values from a known initial value (and not changes of a variable with distance)

Yet I've found both the first and the second in scientific papers (for example, 'the distribution of temperature *T*(*x*) with *x*...' or 'the variation of the Electric field *E*(*r*) with *r* ...') . I also found the 'repartition of the Electric field *E*(*x*) with *x*, but it has only a fraction of the results I found for the other two.

How is most common to describe the changes of the Electric field with the distance/depth in that Figure 1 presented above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure 1 presents the variation of the Electric field with the distance (along the x-axis)

Answer (score 0):

Your number 3 sounds the best to me.
In number 4 you should change a little, to "electric field versus distance" rather than "with distance"